# How do I find the rate of return in R. I am grouping by the data by month

Tags: r

I am trying to find the ratio of the returned orders grouped by month in R. My ratio is exactly one more than what the correct ratio is even after I apply a condition in the numerator.

I have tried grouping by months and then taking ratio of sum of orders which have orderstatus as returned over sum of orders for that particular month

```
casper_orders <- casper_orders %>%
  mutate(dateordered=as.Date(casper_orders$dateordered, "%m/%d/%y"))%>%
  mutate(datereturned=as.Date(casper_orders$datereturned, "%m/%d/%y"))%>%
  group_by(month=floor_date(dateordered, "month")) %>%
  summarize(returnrate=sum(orders,orderstatus %in% c('returned'))/sum(orders))
```

The expected result should be 
month     returnrate
Decemeber 0.04810127

The actual result is 
month     returnrate
Decemeber 1.04810127

Comment: In your last statement, your rate is actually `[sum(order) + sum(returnned order)]/sum(order)` thus esseentially `1 + return rate`? may try this? `summarize(returnrate=sum(orders*(orderstatus %in% c('returned')))/sum(orders))`

Comment: Don't use `data$column` inside dplyr verbs, just use `column`. This will mess up grouped operations. For example, when you have `as.Date(casper_order$dateordered, ...)`, you should just have `as.Date(dateordered, ...)`.